# Is public decimal property threadsafe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a class that has a decimal property accessible from multiple threads

```
public class MyObject
{
    public decimal MyProperty{get; set;}
}
```

Should i use locks inside of get & set?
I understand that decimal is not the type operations with are atomic and decimal uses 96 bits.

Buy it feels very awkward to write locks only for these kinds of types - especially if you are not entirely sure why you doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, operations on decimal are not atomic.

The CLR only guarantees atomicity for reading/writing 32 bit values, and reference sized values. A decimal consists of multiple 32 bit ints, and operations on it are thus not atomic.

---

But usually properties don't need to be thread safe. Typically you use locking on a higher level, where the code knows more about what locking you need.

Even if you'd use locking in the property getter and setter, a simple operation like `MyProperty+=1` wouldn't be thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing and reading the property from different threads on the **same instance of MyObject** then, yes you need to synchronize access to the property. If you are using different instances it will be safe because each thread gets a different instance. It will really depend on your scenario.

Comment: And if i set property only from one thread and getting from multiple?

Comment: @gordava, if this happens on the same instance, then this is not thread safe and you need to synchronize.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx):

> Caution
>
> Assigning an instance of this type is not thread safe on all
> hardware platforms because the binary representation of that instance
> might be too large to assign in a single atomic operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to avoid [torn reads/writes](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2006/02/08/ThreadsafetyTornReadsAndTheLike.aspx) then the answer is yes - your code will work because the CLR automatically aligns these properties at the right boundary(8 in this case), unless you use any of the [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) or [[FieldOffset(…)]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.fieldoffsetattribute.aspx) attributes.

If you need to do more complicated manipulations on the property (like reading **and** writing) then you could use any of the [interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked%28VS.71%29.aspx) constructs. Take a look at the  [Interlocked Anything Pettern](http://alexanderkobelev.blogspot.com/2011/09/interlocked-anything-pattern.html)(ru) too.

Comment: Two threads writing to a `decimal` can lead a "broken" value, where the resulting value is a mix of the two writes.

Comment: Oops, you're right - I was thinking about double when I wrote the above answer !

Comment: Even writes to `Double`s or `Int64`s are not guaranteed to be atomic on 32 bit systems.